# Model selection in nonlinear fitting

Tags: model-selection, goodness-of-fit, nonlinear

Learning curves are fitted with multiple trendlines (exponential, power, logarithm). The fitting is performed by the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm. So far so good.

The question is, how to select the best model (trendline) for each of the learning curves. Currently, the only used factor is MSE. Adjusted R-square was abandoned, since it is not appropriate for nonlinear models.

Is there any other (simple?) metric to compare said three models for goodness of fit? If it matters - the power and exponential trendlines use 3 parameters (intercept included), while the logarithm model uses only 2.

Comment: Maybe try AIC/BIC?

Comment: Maybe try cross-validation?

Comment: You'd need to define "best". Do you want out of sample predictive performance, ... or something else?

Comment: I would like to compare the selected models (trendlines) on a case basis. Currently I am using MSE, which yields a real number where lower means better. If this is not a good measure for goodness of fit, I would like to use a different method/metric.